# Create Fieldcatalog for INCLUDE STRUCTURE types?

Tags: abap, alv

I created a structure with "Types":

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_pers_bst.
     INCLUDE STRUCTURE zieb_pers_bst.
     TYPES: lifname TYPE zieb_lieferant-lifname,
   END OF ty_pers_bst.

data: i_structure_bst_add TYPE ty_pers_bst.
```

I now want to use 'LVC_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE' to create a fieldcatalog based on this structure. However I get the error, that no fieldcatalog can be found.

Is there an alternative on how I can add a single field to a preexisting fieldcatalog based on my "zieb_pers_bst" DDIC-Structure, or do I have to create a new DDIC-Structure solely for this single field?

Comment: I usually use `REUSE_ALV_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE` to auto-generate field catalogs. But I am not sure if that would solve the problem in this particular case.

Comment: And then there is of course the option to just create the table line for that one additional field manually. Building fieldcatalog entries yourself isn't actually that complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this sample:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_pers_bst.
        INCLUDE STRUCTURE a900.
        TYPES: lifname TYPE lfa1-name1,
       END OF ty_pers_bst.

DATA: i_structure_bst_add TYPE TABLE OF ty_pers_bst.

DATA: table TYPE REF TO data.
DATA: fcat  TYPE lvc_t_fcat.
CREATE DATA table LIKE i_structure_bst_add.
ASSIGN table->* TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<table>).
TRY.
    cl_salv_table=>factory( IMPORTING r_salv_table = DATA(salv_table)
                            CHANGING  t_table      = <table> ).
    fcat = cl_salv_controller_metadata=>get_lvc_fieldcatalog(
    r_columns      = salv_table->get_columns( )
    r_aggregations = salv_table->get_aggregations( ) ).
  CATCH cx_root.
ENDTRY.
```